# Useful resources for Anime and Manga fans

Tags: discussion

This post is dedicated to lists of online resources useful for specific tasks. It's not for asking, just for adding whatever you feel like would help others do what anime and manga fans do − buy new anime/manga, translate from/to Japanese, look up characters in a database, identify images, etc.

Purpose of this post: Help users with their questions, redirect users to other sites for things we don't do here. Some lists are [already posted](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) on the main site. This post is for things that don't strictly belong there but are still useful.

Add new resources into existing answers with the corresponding topic or create a new answer if there is no such topic already.

#### Existing topics:

- [A&M databases](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2571)
- [Currently produced A&M](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2576)
- [Recommendations](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2575)
- [Identification](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2572)
- [Conventions](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2574)
- [Merchandise](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2577/191)
- [Translate from/to Japanese](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2570)

#### Possible topics of interest:

- Going to cons as a visitor or seller
- Cosplay making
- Making manga/anime
- Learning how to draw in manga styles
- How to tell if merchandise is good, fake or low-quality, pricing too high
- Where to find anime themed cafes

*Please, check with our list of [legal resources](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/923/191) before adding.*

Answer (score 5):

## Translate from/to Japanese

Want to translate something from Japanese to English or the other way around? Check out this list:

- [Jisho.org](http://jisho.org/) − Japanese from/to English. Supports romaji, kanji;
- [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#ja/en/) − Japanese from/to most languages. Supports kanji (with hand-drawn option);

Comment: Note: Google Translate can be relatively shoddy at times when doing Japanese to English translations for larger chunks of texts (but we all know that). Less obviously, Google Translate also can fail horribly when translation from Japanese _to other languages that aren't English_, because of the translation mechanism. (Google translates the original language to English, and then the result to the target language: something which I readily confirmed by testing whether differentiation between different forms of "you" would be preserved when translating from French to German.)

Answer (score 5):

## Identify anime/manga image

Purposes: Identify anime, manga, characters by image;

[**See this post on the main site**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/how-can-i-identify-the-source-of-an-anime-image-using-reverse-image-search)

Answer (score 4):

## Conventions

Purposes: Find conventions, location, date;

- [Where can I get listings of convention locations and dates?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22856/where-can-i-get-listings-of-convention-locations-and-dates/22857)

Answer (score 4):

## Recommendations

Purposes: Get recommendations, suggestions; Find similar, related anime/manga;

- [You want recommendations? Here's a list of them](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/you-want-recommendations-heres-a-list-of-them) − our own recommendations list on Meta;
- [Are there any anime suggestion engines?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7337/are-there-any-anime-suggestion-engines/7341) − dedicated site list

Answer (score 4):

## Currently produced anime/manga

Purposes: Find out what anime is airing now, what manga is still in production; Airing dates, time;

- [Where do I find a table / listing of all currently airing anime series?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/156/where-do-i-find-a-table-listing-of-all-currently-airing-anime-series)

Answer (score 4):

## Merchandise

Purposes: Learn how, where to buy anime/manga related merchandise; Product quality; Pricing;

#### Figurines

- [How can I tell if an anime figure is a fake?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22297/how-can-i-tell-if-an-anime-figure-is-a-fake)

#### Other

- [Where can I buy anime cel sheets?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/9842/where-can-i-buy-anime-cel-sheets)

Answer (score 3):

## Anime and Manga databases

Purposes: Look up the full name, short name, English name, Japanese name, alternative name; Read reviews, synopses, descriptions; Look up the list of characters, character names, voice actors; Related works; Genre, tags; Ratings; Airing dates;

[**See this post on the main site**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/what-databases-and-listing-sites-exist-for-anime-manga-etc)