# Can I ask for anime suggestions here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I am wondering if I can ask for anime series suggestions and recommendations, or would that be to broad?

Comment: No , read [here](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope, mostly because it's opinion-based.

We do have some general recommendations here though - [You want recommendations? Here's a list of them](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/you-want-recommendations-heres-a-list-of-them)

Or you can come talk in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-